# Resizing window offscreen

Tags: macos, window-manager

I have a macbook pro running Mountain Lion. I have a problem with the maximum window height. It looks like all the windows have to be in between the menu bar and dock. I sometimes need to have simulators which runs for iPad retina size and doesn't fit in my widescreen. Is there any way I can let them resize to their full height and width without OSX forcing them to resize?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can usually just move a window to the bottom of the screen and then resize it by dragging the top edge up.

These commands don't usually resize windows so that they are outside screens:

- `tell application "SomeApp" to set bounds of window 1 to {0, 0, 9999, 9999}`
- `tell application "SomeApp" to set size of window 1 to {9999, 9999}`
- `tell application "System Events" to tell process "SomeApp" to set size of window 1 to {9999, 9999}`